# Do I need specific IP addresses to configure SPF for a site hosted by AWS?

Tags: email, email-server

I noticed when our application sends an email to a user, it goes to spam. I did some research and tested the SPF record for our domain and subdomain. No SPF record was detected.

When I brought this up, a co-worker wh tells me that Amazon's IP addresses are dynamic and we would have to keep changing the spf records.

I have known about SPF for a humble 2 hours, but I think that what he is saying sounds like nonsense. Can't SPF just be configured generically for an entire domain?

Comment: If you assign an EIP, you can maintain IP addresses through reboots.

Answer (score 1):

If that IP address is one you're using in, say, an `A` record (i.e., those servers are hosting a website) then you can just have the `SPF` record use those DNS entries in the lookup:

```
v=spf1 a:thoseservers.example.com -all
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include more background and clarity, but I think what you are saying is confirming my thought. We don't need specific ip addresses for this. That's what dns is for. if you said a:example.com, would that create valid spf for emails sent from all subdomains?

Comment: no, a:example.com means check the IP address of example.com and allow all those IP addresses to send on your behalf.

Comment: @bingo No - the SPF resolver needs to be able to get back to actual IP addresses from what's there - it can do an `A` lookup for `example.com` but not for `*.example.com`.

Comment: @ShaneMadden the email may be sent from example.com or www.example.com. Do I need two separate SPF records then?

Comment: @bingo Nope, `v=spf1 a:example.com a:www.example.com -all` will use both of those `A` records which should cover it.

Answer (score 1):

1) What kind of application do you use that is changing it's IP address frequently.

2) SPF is a server authentication by IP address, you can use dns mechanisms (such as a:example.com) but you may want to look into using an ESP (Email Service Provider).

3) Email Systems rely on **Reputation**, use an ESP that monitors abuse and maintains a solid reputation to send out notifications, this would be configured as a Smart-Host, and can be configured many ways, I would recommend [MandrillApp](https://mandrillapp.com) or [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/), both have a plethora of documentation for new users and have a huge (12K emails per month) allowance for free users.

Option 3 is your best bet to attain increased deliverability without spending a lot of time and money into a solid email delivery system.

Comment: To address number 1: An AWS EC2 instance will receive a new public ip address from Amazon's public ip address pool if the instance is stopped and then started. Note that this doesn't occur when the instance is restarted/rebooted. If an instance needs a permanent, static ip address than it needs to be assigned an Elastic ip address. One Elastic ip address per **running** instance is free.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty, I'm not familiar all things aws.

Comment: Glad to help. I wasn't familiar either until I dipped my toes in the AWS pool recently.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SES to send email, you cannot use a plain `a:example.com` SPF entry to send SPF valid emails using SES. The Amazon SES group [recommends that you use an IP address list in the SPF record](https://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxEH4YOF3YJG0L/Amazon-SES-IP-addresses).

Please note that while these IP addresses can change, they have been the same since the publication of that post in June 2013. It does not appear that they change frequently.